# Angular :has selector not working correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, firefox, sass

I am trying to get the has selector to work with angular.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="check-list no-bullet-points mb-0">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of checkList.items">
        <li class="d-flex flex-row gap-3 align-items-center" [ngClass]="{ 'checklist-item-bigger': bigger }">
          <i class="item-icon fa-solid {{ item.icon }}"></i>
          <div class="item-text font-weight-bold">{{ item.text }}</div>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
```

I am trying to display two rows if there are more than 5 li present. I could assign a new class with [ngClass] but as far as I am aware it should work with pure css.
This is my selector:

```
.check-list:has(li:nth-child(5)) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  li {
    width: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
```

However this has no effect. Does ng-container cause issues witht this selector? I am using firefox but as far as I am aware Firefox supports the :has selector fully.

The css itself works fine when I remove the selector, but I think im doing something wrong.

Comment: Firefox [supports](https://caniuse.com/?search=%20%3Ahas) behind the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled flag`

Comment: Keep in mind that is a CSS feature which has nothing to do with Angular

Comment: @ChrisBarr yeah I know, I just thought the ng-container might influence the selector somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have `:has` pseudo-class support enabled by default.

It is currently behind the flag `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` since v103.:

You can follow the feature implementation [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039#c62).